# evaluating string to arrayname

Tags: jquery, arraylist

I have created some array as below

```
var GP = ["Doc_Type", "Approval_Type"];
var AB = ["XX", "YY"];
```

I have select with option value as same name of array name as below

```
<select id="dpSelect">
<option value="">Select Tender Type</option>
<option value="GP">First Option</option>
<option value="AB">Second Option</option>
```

I was trying to loop array as per the selection of dropdown. But it gives error. Somebody show me clean way to do that

```
$.each(eval($("#dpSelect").val()), function (i, doctype) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jQuery .change() event to identify when the selection in the dropdown changes, and then you can use eval() to get the corresponding array name:

```
$("#dpSelect").change(function()
{
    if ($(this).val())
    {
        var dpArray = eval($(this).val());
        for (var i = 0; i < dpArray.length; i++)
        {
            // custom code here
        }  
    }
});
```

I created a quick JSFiddle showing this in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/trgto8to/